# czech char '&#283;' on php page script

Tags: php, character-encoding, iso-8859-2

I'm not able to correctly show this char on my web pages. I'm using UTF-8 charset for this page, have I to use ISO-8859-2? I'm getting this a string with this char from a db and on it, it's saved as `&#283;`. My Browser show only html tag.

It's the only char (at this moment) that I can't show on my webpage. I've take a look to the http://www.czech.cz and they use UTF-8.

any suggests?

take care!
Andrea

Comment: How about a link to your page?

Comment: http://www.fornacigrigolin.it/cz/ProdottiFamiglia.php?id_cat=2

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing the `&#283;` in the browser, or when you view source?  If you're seeing it in the browser, then it's probably being double-encoded somewhere -- whatever outputs it to the page is probably detecting it as unencoded HTML and is trying to protect you from some kind of HTML-injection.  You'll want to make it not do that.  But you have an even deeper problem.  If your page is served up in UTF-8, and your data is in UTF-8, there isn't any reason to turn it into an HTML entity in the first place.  You should be passing through the UTF-8 data.  You do *not* need to switch to a different character encoding.

Comment: It's my browser that it's not able to translate the '&@ 283;' code. There is also a problem. I've an admin page to upload on db the string, and before update on db I call $text=htmlentities($text,ENT_QUOTES);. For all other languages all is correct, but not for this char.....

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars` **not** `htmlentities`. `htmlentities` tries to encode all non-ASCII characters, which is needless and will corrupt them if you don't tell it the right character set. It defaults to nasty old ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, yes, you really should be using UTF-8.  But that doesn't mean the data you have is already UTF-8 encoded.

Secondly, it sounds like that character is HTML encoded in the database *already*. This is a problem, because it seems that whatever page is displaying this character *also* tries to HTML-encode the content as well.  Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

Data from user: `ě`
Data HTML encoded (via [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/htmlentities)) prior to going into DB: `&#283;`
Data stored in DB: `&#283;`
Data retrieved from DB: `&#283;`
Data HTML encoded before being printed to the page: `&amp;#283;`
Data as seen in the browser: `&#283;`

Do you see that? The character becomes *double encoded*, so that on the 2nd encoding step the ampersand character is converted into an entity itself.

This is the problem with HTML-encoding data before storing it in the database.  That should only be done prior to displaying the content, not prior to storage.

Comment: You are the man! It's exactly the problem..... So, I've to remove the htmlentities() prior to dong into DB, is it?

Comment: But It's not so clear why on db I've this "Vrchn&iacute; om&iacute;tky a vyrovn&aacute;vac&ia." and it's correctly shown on my browser...

Comment: You should use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting text into the HTML page, and `htmlentities` never. Don't HTML-escape content going into the database.

Comment: Ok, I've found the problem. The char is coded on DB as &amp;#283; How can I prevent this?

Comment: I've remove the htmlentities and changed the charset to ISO-8859-1 and it works fine.

Comment: It works only because your content is still HTML-encoded in the database.  If you ever repair that data (or remove the step that encodes it) then ISO-8859-1 won't be sufficient.

Comment: I've suffered from this issue myself. I'm not sure yet about who's to blame about it but it happens when you need to store a character that is not allowed in the database character set. The only reasonable fix is to change the DB charset to another one with a wider character set, such as UTF-8, or reject the input data when in contains invalid chars.